# 0 in switch case?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Sorry for maybe dumb question, but i have HUGE problem with one case when i have some int variable with value of 0(zero).

```
            switch ($starost_vozila){
                case (0):
                    switch ($podaci['tip_motora']){
                        case ("motor1"):
                            $eko_taksa = 485;
                        break;
                        case ("motor2"):
                            $eko_taksa = 243;
                        break;
                        case ("motor3"):
                            $eko_taksa = 121;
                        break;
                        case ("motor4"):
                            $eko_taksa = 194;
                        break;
                    }
                break;
                case ($starost_vozila < 6):
                    switch ($podaci['tip_motora']){
                        case ("motor1"):
                            $eko_taksa = 485;
                        break;
                        case ("motor2"):
                            $eko_taksa = 243;
                        break;
                        case ("motor3"):
                            $eko_taksa = 121;
                        break;
                        case ("motor4"):
                            $eko_taksa = 194;
                        break;
                    }
                break;
                case ($starost_vozila > 5 && $starost_vozila < 11):
                    switch ($podaci['tip_motora']){
                        case ("motor1"):
                            $eko_taksa = 667;
                        break;
                        case ("motor2"):
                            $eko_taksa = 273;
                        break;
                        case ("motor3"):
                            $eko_taksa = 136;
                        break;
                        case ("motor4"):
                            $eko_taksa = 218;
                        break;
                    }
                break;
```

Switch continue more, but here is my problem, in this piece of code.

If i dont put "case (0):" and use this:

```
case ($starost_vozila >= 0 && $starost_vozila < 6):
```

Then the case that is next will somehow become active and it will print out that "$eko_taksa = 667;".

That is all problem when "$starost_vozila = 0" but when it is any number less then 6 than this case above works.

Every var here is int. Everything works ok except when "$starost_vozila = 0" **and when i use** "case ($starost_vozila >= 0 && $starost_vozila < 6):".

I have no idea what is going on... Oo

Sorry if this is dumb question. :(

Comment: //offtopic My personal advice is to use english words when naming your variables. For example I understand them, but probably most of the visitors here - don't. It's a good practice though. Sys Zdrave! :)

Comment: Ran in a similar situation, banged my head against the wall and found this. Thanks so much for posting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

switch cases don't take statements that need to be evaluated. They take simple strings, booleans or numbers to be compared against

so say you have

```
$x = 0

switch( $x ) {
    case( $x < 10 ):
    ...
    break;
}
```

you are expecting that case to run but it doesn't and here's why

`( $x < 10 )` evaluates to `true`
so what you actually have is:

```
$x = 0

switch( $x ) {
    case true: //!!!
    ...
    break;
}
```

`0 != true` so the case fails

you need to use

```
if() {

} else if() {

} else {

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what i needed to find hear and make everything clear. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, As mentioned in the question it works for all expect when the value is 0, so is it ok to use switch case for all other cases and use if else only when its 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `switch` incorrectly.

Your code is understood like this:

```
if ($starost_vozila == 0) {
    switch ($podaci['tip_motora']){
        case ("motor1"):
            $eko_taksa = 485;
        break;
        case ("motor2"):
            $eko_taksa = 243;
        break;
        case ("motor3"):
            $eko_taksa = 121;
        break;
        case ("motor4"):
            $eko_taksa = 194;
        break;
    }
} else if ($starost_vozila == ($starost_vozila < 6)) { //not what you want!!!
    switch ($podaci['tip_motora']){
        case ("motor1"):
            $eko_taksa = 485;
        break;
        case ("motor2"):
            $eko_taksa = 243;
        break;
        case ("motor3"):
            $eko_taksa = 121;
        break;
        case ("motor4"):
            $eko_taksa = 194;
        break;
    }
} else if ($starost_vozila == ($starost_vozila > 5 && $starost_vozila < 11)) { //not what you want!!!
    switch ($podaci['tip_motora']){
        case ("motor1"):
            $eko_taksa = 667;
        break;
        case ("motor2"):
            $eko_taksa = 273;
        break;
        case ("motor3"):
            $eko_taksa = 136;
        break;
        case ("motor4"):
            $eko_taksa = 218;
        break;
    }
}
```

For example, `($starost_vozila < 6)` will become either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `$starost_vozila == ($starost_vozila < 6)` is comparing `$starost_vozila` to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which is not what you want to do.

I suggest using `if`/`elseif` rather than `switch` in this case. For example:

```
if ($starost_vozila == 0) {
    ...
} else if ($starost_vozila < 6) {
    ...
} else if ($starost_vozila > 5 && $starost_vozila < 11) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using Switch is like == in "if statement" and not  === (doesn't check for type).   Only empty string or NULL would result in an Integer 0 - other than that, they are considered string 0.